# Mongodb $in query for Array not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Below is the schema of document in mongo db

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d9a2f467d16f15a886a532"),
    "Author" : "RYTnirY",
    "Title" : "MZDCGMyXLV",
    "Content" : "HotEXFcyjaipabbAXAkKR",
    "Tags" : [ 
        "oHE,SJx,FMQ"
    ],
    "CreatedAtUtc" : ISODate("2015-08-23T10:39:48.766Z"),
    "Comments" : [ 
        {
            "Author" : "RWfSxDZ",
            "Content" : "TvYfJzLtIeaIdrxdsbQ",
            "CreatedAtUtc" : Date(-62135596800000)
        }, 
        {
            "Author" : "RFmUqfD",
            "Content" : "lHpUwrLnzXMSFtpGmo",
            "CreatedAtUtc" : Date(-62135596800000)
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all documents with a specific tag for example only by oHE or oHE,SJx . I am not able to find correct query .

```
db.poss.find({ Tags: { $in: { [ "oHE","SJx" ] } }})
```

Comment: @Rudra Comments like that are the reason I personally wish that comments should be able to be downvoted. Completely incorrect.

Comment: Also since all of your dates here work out to be the "1st January 01" ( as in year 1 A.D ) then I suggest you have quite a few problems here as well as the fact that your "array" only contains a singular string and not an array of strings, as you seem to expect it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stored tags as single array item `["oHE,SJx,FMQ"]` instead of multiple items `["oHE", "SJx, "FMQ"]` that's why query doesn't work.

You can convert tags string to array using code bellow:

```
var cursor = db.poss.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  var x = cursor.next();
  var tags = x['Tags'][0];
  print("Before: "+x['Tags']);
  x['Tags'] = tags.split(',');
  print("After: "+x['Tags']);
  db.poss.update({_id : x._id}, x);
}
```

or

```
db.poss.find().forEach(function (el) {
    var tags = el.Tags[0];
    el.Tags = tags.split(',');
    db.poss.save(el);
});
```

Comment: Show them how to correct the data and it's a vote from me.

Comment: Not "optimal", but certainly better than other responses here. Learn about [Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations, and also why [update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/operator/update-field/) are preferred over `.save()`. But enough to get the OP here on the correct track.

Comment: Thanks for quick information it helped . The problem was with my class design .

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all - make it `["oHE", "SJx, "FMQ"]` instead of `["oHE,SJx,FMQ"]`.
Then change your query to `db.poss.find({Tags: {$in: ["oHE", "SJx"] }})`

Comment: Thanks for quick information it helped . The problem was with my class design .

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using [Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations

```js
var bulk = db.poss.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.poss.find().forEach(function(doc){ 
    var tag = doc.Tags[0].split(","); 
    bulk.find({"_id": doc._id}).updateOne({
        "$set": { "Tags": tag }
    }); 
    count++; 
    if (count % 500 == 0){
        // Execute per 500 operations and re-init
        bulk.execute();     
        bulk = db.poss.initializeOrderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

// Clean up queues
if ( count % 500 != 0 )
    bulk.execute()
```

Then your data look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55d9a2f467d16f15a886a532"),
        "Author" : "RYTnirY",
        "Title" : "MZDCGMyXLV",
        "Content" : "HotEXFcyjaipabbAXAkKR",
        "Tags" : [
                "oHE",
                "SJx",
                "FMQ"
        ],
        "CreatedAtUtc" : ISODate("2015-08-23T10:39:48.766Z"),
        "Comments" : [
                {
                        "Author" : "RWfSxDZ",
                        "Content" : "TvYfJzLtIeaIdrxdsbQ",
                        "CreatedAtUtc" : "Sun Aug 23 2015 15:22:04 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
                },
                {
                        "Author" : "RFmUqfD",
                        "Content" : "lHpUwrLnzXMSFtpGmo",
                        "CreatedAtUtc" : "Sun Aug 23 2015 15:22:04 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
                }
        ]
}
```

Now your query:

```js
db.poss.find({ "Tags": { "$in": [ "oHE","SJx" ]  }})
```